# Array sort on datetime

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime

I'm having some problems trying to sort my array on a time. The array has a value with minutes, the lowest has to show at the top.

This is my array:

```
$voertuigen[] = array(
'img' => $img,
'nummer' => $nummer,
'soort' => $rnaam,
'aankomst' => $formatted
);
```

I've tryed to use sort()

```
sort($voertuigen, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

But then I get this:
9:42
10:50
9:42
13:43
It isn't correctly sorted.

Thanks for helping!

It isn't a datetime, it is just something like this: 10:30 - Minutes:seconds

Comment: So where are you telling your sort to sort against a datetime? Which is the datetime?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell, the 'aankomst' is the one with the datetime

Comment: That post doesn't help me. My value is like 10:00 -- Minutes:Seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `usort` to define your own comparison and then use `DateTime` to parse the times in the array and then compare them:

```
usort($voertuigen, function ($a, $b) {
    return new DateTime($a['aankomst']) > new DateTime($b['aankomst']);
});
```

Hope this helps!